# Filezilla connection error

Tags: linux, windows, proxy, rhel5, ftp

I have Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 5 LAN server with [Squid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_%28software%29) 2.6 stable proxy settings.

Under this have some Windows XP desktops.

Now I installed [FileZilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FileZilla) FTP client in Windows XP, to service my client's websites.

But I can't connect FTP servers through FileZilla.

I set generic proxy too. (HTTP/1.1 USING CONNECT method.)

I get an error message,

> Status: Connecting to (ftp hostname) through proxy
>
> Status: Connecting to hostname:port...
>
> Status: Connection with proxy established, performing handshake...
>
> Response: Proxy reply: HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Frequently, corporate web proxies will allow a CONNECT to port 443 only. Filezilla will be attempting to connect to port 21 (FTP command port) through your proxy but your proxy is telling you that is forbidden.

So how to get around this? Set up a virtual machine running Linux somewhere on the public internet. Configure port 443 as a SSH server port. Use putty to make a connection via your web proxy to port 443 on your virtual server, and set up SOCKS proxying through that connection (tunnel). Finally, configure Filezilla to use your local SOCKS proxy (which is really redirecting connections to your virtual Linux host through the SSH tunnel established over your web proxy).